# What are some of the scenarios that can make foreign keys become untrusted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an OLTP and an OLAP database where we keep a rolling 13 months of data in the OLAP.  Several ETL job keeps the OLAP up to date with nightly jobs and none of the jobs disable foreign key while ETL is being performed.  Occasionally, due to reasons I have not yet uncovered, some of my OLTP foreign keys become untrusted.  I use the following script below (thanks to Brent Ozar's group) to identify and then fix these keys.

My question is: Other than manually disabling and then forgetting to re-enable keys, what scenarios can cause a foreign key to become untrusted?  I have scoured our ETL jobs and nothing sticks out.

**Scripts to identify and then fix untrusted keys:**

**Identifying Untrusted Keys**

The following script, compliments of the Brent Ozar group, will help identify untrusted keys.  Note that this script must be run while connected to the given database you wish to examine.

```
SELECT '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].[' + i.name + ']' AS keyname
from sys.foreign_keys i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0

SELECT '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].[' + i.name + ']' AS keyname
from sys.check_constraints i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0 AND i.is_disabled = 0
```

**Repairing Untrusted Keys**

Once you have identified untrusted keys, use the following script to re-enable them:

*ALTER TABLE MyTableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraintName*

Large tables will take time so this should be performed during a maintenance window.  You may find key values that do not adhere to the constraint rules since the keys were disabled.  These values will need to be edited or the rows deleted in order to successfully re-enable the key.

*Alter Table Scripts for PriceGuide and PriceGuideDW*

I have made some modifications to the Brent Ozar scripts specifically for our databases.  These scripts will generate the necessary alter table scripts to fix the untrusted keys:

```
Use PriceGuide
Go 
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + o.name + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' +
--'[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].
+ '[' + i.name + '];' AS keyname
from sys.foreign_keys i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0

SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + o.name + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' +
--'[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].
+ '[' + i.name + '];' AS keyname
from sys.check_constraints i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0 AND i.is_disabled = 0

Use PriceGuideDW
Go 
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + o.name + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' +
--'[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].
+ '[' + i.name + '];' AS keyname
from sys.foreign_keys i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0

SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + o.name + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' +
--'[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].
+ '[' + i.name + '];' AS keyname
from sys.check_constraints i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0 AND i.is_disabled = 0
```

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this script in order to remove the unused foreign keys?

Comment: So you want to drop foreign keys that are untrusted?  If so, use the first script to identify the objects ( table and foreign key) and then build a script like this: alter table <table name> drop <foreign key name>

Comment: Is there a way that these two scripts could be combined? Search through the DB for disabled/untrusted FKs and drop them as you meet them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, adding the foreign key `WITH NOCHECK` is certainly the first way that comes to mind.

Comment: Agreed but what I'm seeing is keys that are created WITH CHECK that appear to enforce referential integrity for some time (months at a time) but then somehow become untrusted.

Comment: Then someone must have disabled them, possibly to enable some change to be made to the referenced table... can't think of any other way they can become untrusted.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to use `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` in order to verify that the existing data meets the constraint.  If you go back to Brent Ozar's site, that is what they prescribe.  http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/